# Method when Fragment comes to the screen in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

In my application, I have a ViewPager which holds many swipeable Tabs with Fragments inside. Is there a method like `onResume` which is called every time the fragment comes to the screen? `onResume, onCreateView` and so on are called after the Fragment is created and not if it comes to the screen, so they do not work for me. Which method can I use for my problem?

Comment: `ViewPager` with swipable tabs? By that do you mean you have views for `ViewPager`? If fragment is created everytime when you swipe the pager, then you have many methods of `Fragment` which you can use. Check out fragment lifecycle for more detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use setUserVisibleHint method in your fragment:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser){
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisibleToUser){
        // Your fragment is visible
    }
}
```